# While using UIImagePickerController in Xamarin.iOS, when I select any front cam image, it gets rotated 90 degrees counter clockwise

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, xamarin-studio

I am using Xamarin Studio an UIImagePickerController to pick an Image from the Gallery and put that Image on a UIButton. Everything seems to work fine, but whenever I select an Image captured by the front cam in Portrait mode, the image automatically gets rotated by 90 degrees counter clockwise. Can anybody help me with the C# code for making the rotation right.
I referred to many answers for this, but nothing seems to workout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see https://gist.github.com/unhappy224/0979b5c83bab14578254

you should fix image orientation